# My MBP (13 inch, MID 2010) will not start up

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, startup, sudo

I have used the internet for the past 2 weeks in search of something that will help me troubleshoot/repair my MBP. It wont boot in Safe Mode using the SHIFT key. Following is everything I have tried and the results:

Safe Mode Boot - Failed

Command R - Failed

AHT - No Errors Found

Reset the Power Manager SHIFT+LEFTOPTION+LEFTCONTROL+POWER - PRAM Reset

Terminal Commands: `fsck_hsf`, `fsck -y`, `fsck -yf`, `fsck -f`, `/sbin/fsck -f`, `fsck -yf`, and many more.

> RESULTS: SINGLEUSER BOOT FSCK NOT DONE, ROOT DEVICE IS MOUNTED READ
>   ONLY, FSCK_HFS: VOLUME IS JOURNALED. NO CHECKING PERFORMED, FSCK_HFS:
>   USE THE -F OPTION TO FORCE CHECKING. THE VOLUME MACINTOSH HD APPEARS
>   TO BE OKAY.

cd `/Volumes/Recovery HD/com.apple.recovery.boot` - cd: `/VOLUMES/RECOVERY`: No such file or directory.

Using the OPTION key only brings up one HD and it's not the one that should say RECOVERY DISK.

Help me please. I am not sure what needs to be done at this point. I can't perform some commands because I am in single user mode and it does not allow that. I'm not sure how to actually use the terminal to allow me to use SUDO.

I was able to get the following information from the Terminal. Hopefully this will be enough for someone to help me. I don't want to give out some information if it is a security feature.

```
IOAPIA: VERSION Ox11 
PCI CONFIGURATION

EBEA116D-....-....-8035-............
APPLEINTELCPUPOWERMGMTCLIENT: READY
BTCOEXIST; OFF
5.--.---.42
FIREWIRE LUCENT ID ....
BUILTIN NOW ACTIVE
GUID 603..........D5C
ROOT DEVICE IS MOUNTED READ ONLY
```

I hope someone can provide some insight.

Comment: Sounds like you have tried a lot. Take it to the Apple Store.

Comment: That's what I figured but does it matter whether or not it was given to me. I didn't purchase it.  A friend knew I worked on computers and their in-law was going to throw it away because they purchased another one and they mailed it to me.

Comment: Will they also mail you the install/startup disk that came with that computer? Because it did. And by starting up from a boot disk or bootable external drive, Disk Utility can perform repairs that cannot be done from the HD itself. Or perhaps you know someone with an install disk close enough to that model.

Comment: All Genius Bar are free. You will get a professional opinion and a quote (that you can decline) for any hardware repairs that may be needed. http://concierge.apple.com/reservation/us/en/techsupport/ to make an appointment.